# Xcode failed to install

Tags: xcode

I am trying to install [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 4.2 on my [Mac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh) system having OS version 10.6.8.
Actually, I removed the Xcode from the system and tried to reinstall it.

I quit [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) before installing it, and I have enough free space on disc (111 GB). Below is a screenshot of the error. What should I do?

[image: Screnshot]

Comment: Have you downloaded the original digital download from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: 111mb doesn't sound like a whole lot.  You may have run out of scratch space.

Comment: @Sree....yes i downloaded the dmg from the same!

Comment: @HotLicks..sorry its 111GB!It was a mistake!

Comment: I have faced the problem once, i have restarted the system and then i made the installation, it worked well

Comment: Even restarting the system not helping...???

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Set your system time to 1st January 2012 or earlier (but not too early), as the certificate that signed the package has expired.

Comment: No problem - can you please click the outline of a tick to mark my answer as accepted? (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: It almost look like April Fools, nice answer.

Comment: Holy crap, i was moments away from reformatting my drive. I would have never thought of that. Thank soooooo much!

Comment: That's insane. Like *literally* insane. Why does it behave that way? Thank you very much!

Comment: It behaves that way because the package is signed by Apple's certificate. If there is a signature mismatch or the certificate has expired, to protect you, Apple disables Xcode from being installed. Therefore by rewinding your computer's date you trick it into thinking that the certificate is valid. If only the error message were more helpful...!

Comment: i changed my date back after installing it....but my browser(safari) was working erractically...!

Comment: That's to be expected. You can put the date forward once installed.

Comment: I <3 you. I just installed OSX on a VBOX and had a time figuring out why XCode was refusing to install. I was just about to give up  thinking it's a VM issue before I saw this. Works perfectly! Have an upvote sir (I'd give you 2 if that was possible).

Comment: Changing the date solved the issue. But I wonder how did that idea came to your mind? The error message did not say anything about certificate being expired.

Comment: There was a very similar question on here which had a more detailed error message relating to invalid certificates, and so with the help of Google I pinned the problem down to an expired certificate.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  Apple's "it just works" mantra doesn't always apply to their dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error message. In my case, it was solved by updating the OS software. There was an update waiting for "Apple installations software". After the update, Xcode installed perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could download the installer directly from Apple instead of through the app store, and that the error described by the accepted answer could also be circumvented by installing the Mobile Development Framework manually.

See forum post *[Problems installing Xcode on Lion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3771396?start=0&tstart=0)* for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble on Mac OS 10.8.5 when installing Xcode 4.4.1, Xcode 5.1.1, and Security_Update_2014-005. It turned out that the reason was the same in all these cases: an incompatibility with Vodafone/Huawei UMTS drivers. A workaround in this case is to temporarily move them away, e.g.

```
mv /System/Library/Extensions/{HuaweiDataCardDriver.kext,Vodafone.kext,VodafoneFilter.kext} ~
```

Then do the installation/update, and then restore those drivers, e.g.,

```
mv ~/{HuaweiDataCardDriver.kext,Vodafone.kext,VodafoneFilter.kext} /System/Library/Extensions/
```