# Reinstalling Xcode

Tags: xcode

I deleted the Xcode file in the applications folder and empty the trash. I never uninstalled it properly. Now I'd like to reinstall it but there is an unknown error during installation. Is there any way to fix it to install Xcode properly?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you attempting to reinstall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode Installation failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964528/xcode-installation-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming Xcode 4.2 or below)
Set your system time to 1st January 2012 or earlier (but not too early), as the certificate that signed the package has expired.